# Keeping original indexes while sorting using Merge Sort in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I'm trying to sort a list with Merge Sort algoritm, while keeping it's original indices. I was told that the straight-forward solution was to use an array of indexes (obviously it would be initialized to 0 1 2 3...), and change it inside the merge-sort, as I change the corresponding values in the original array.
The thing is, I can't find a way to make it work, because merge sort doesn't use the indexes of the original array, but rather the indexes of the small arrays that the original array splits into. I guess I'm missing something here... the solution I thought about so far was to treat the indexes array just as the original one, I mean split it into smaller arrays, declare a "helperIndexArray" for the new indexes, call merge with those variables etc... But it seems really unefficient. Isn't there a better way?
I'd appreciate any tips, thanks!

```
void internalMsort(int array[], int size, int helperArray[], int index[]) {
    int left = size / 2, right = size - left;
    if (size < 2)
        return;
    internalMsort(array, left, helperArray);
    internalMsort(array + left, right, helperArray);
    merge(array, left, array + left, right, helperArray, index);
    memCpy(array, helperArray, size);
}

void merge(int a[], int na, int b[], int nb, int c[], index[]) {
int ia, ib, ic;
   for(ia = ib = ic = 0; (ia < na) && (ib < nb); ic++)
     {
       if(a[ia] < b[ib]) {
           c[ic] = a[ia];
           ia++;
           // here I was trying to swap index[ic] with index[ia] but it didn't work
       }
       else {
           c[ic] = b[ib];
           ib++;
       }
   }
   for(;ia < na; ia++, ic++){ c[ic] = a[ia]; }
   for(;ib < nb; ib++, ic++) { c[ic] = b[ib]; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a new type called tuple:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    size_t index;
} tuple;
```

Create an array of tuples, fill it with values, and set the indexes in order, from 0 to size-1.

Then sort  the array using the member value, and ignore the member index.

The resulting array will be sorted and its elements will contain the original index in the member index.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy (and not specific to *mergesort*). Just create an array of

```
 struct element_and_index_st  {
    int element;
    size_t original_index; // could be an `int` or an `unsigned`
 };
```

and sort that array, providing a compare function which only compares the `element` field.

<sup>(unless your array is huge, you practically can have the `original_index` be some `int` or some `unsigned` on current desktops or laptops, where `int`s have 32 bits at least)</sup>

But you don't tell why you need the original indexes and how will you give them back to your caller?

Perhaps you just want some [*stable sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) ?

Answer (score 0):

First sort the indices according to the array (compare array[index[ia]] <= array[index[ic]] to sort index[]. Use the helper array as the second array for the indices. Since both the array and the indices are integers, you can use the helper array to sort the array after the indices are sorted:

```
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        helperArray = array[index[i]];
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        array[i] = helperArray[i];
```